# JDBC Connection Link Failure - How to fail over?

Tags: java, database-connection

I have a stand-alone Java windows application developed based on Swing. It connects to a MySQL database for data storage. In case the database connection fails, I am getting a link failure exception from the MySQL JDBC driver (MySQLNonTransientConnectionException).  I don't want to re-instantiate my database connection object or the whole program in case such a link failure issue happens. I just want to tell the user to try again later without having to restart the entire application. If the user is asked to restart the entire application, that would probably give a negative impression on the quality of the program. What do you think would be the preferred way for a standard java application to fail-over after such a database link failure without having to re-instantiate all the communication objects? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see how your program could continue to run without opening a new connection.

Comment: You have to code it according to your requirements - `if database_dead display message`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Connection Pool (such as C3PO or DBCP). Your application takes the Connections from the pool, executes the statement(s) and puts the Connection back into the pool. The pool can be configured to test the JDBC Connections. For example, if they become stale, they can be automatically reinstantiated by the pool.

If your application takes the Connection from the pool, it will be a valid Connection. Let the pool handle the management of valid/invalid/stale JDBC Connections.